# AuthN in Cadence

Tags: authorization, cadence-workflow

Could someone explain the process to enable authorization in Uber Cadence? I would like a detailed explanation because I'm very confused with this topic and how to solve it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: The design is being reviewed. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FlcI5UYk1hOyXe7WHMAjeh0fJCxPfXTiOKKRxuDVZ2I/edit#

Comment: Cadence team is working on a flexible/unified AuthN solution and the proposal is being reviewed. Feel free to comment to let us know if there is any standard for this type of authN request/response.

Answer (score 0):

After https://github.com/uber/cadence/issues/2833 , Cadence has a AuthN interface and already plumbed through the system. However, it requires users to implement the interface and then re-compile the binary to use(internally this is how Uber uses it). This is not convenient because users have to make code change.

It's been becoming more frequent asks recently. I open this [issue](https://github.com/uber/cadence/issues/3920) to track the feature. We probably can prioritize it in next quarters.